# How do you override a readonly property to readwrite in sub class

Tags: ios, swift, properties

I'd like to override a readonly property and make it read/writable.

The super class. This is in a framework so I can't rewrite it in Swift.

```
@interface AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider : AWSAbstractIdentityProvider
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *providerName;
// (...)
@end
```

When I import the framework above, XCode7's interface preview was like this:

```
public class AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider : AWSAbstractIdentityProvider {
    public var providerName: String! { get }
    // (...)
}
```

Now, the sub class definition. This class is defined in the app, so I'm trying to rewrite it in Swift.

```
// .h file
@interface AppIdentityProvider : AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider
@end

// .m file
@interface AppIdentityProvider ()
@property (strong, atomic) NSString *providerName; // <=== THIS: Redeclare by removing readonly
@end

@implementation AppIdentityProvider
@synthesize providerName=_providerName;  // <=== and this

// ...
@end
```

How do you transcode the property above?

I tried the following:

```
public class AppIdentityProviderSwift: AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider
{

    public override var providerName: String! {
        get { return super.providerName }
        set { super.providerName = newValue } // <== compile error, the property is read only
    }
    // (...)
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a backing variable to your class. That should be fine if you don't need to call your superclass' setter.

```
class AppIdentityProviderSwift : AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider {
    private final var _providerName : String!
    override var providerName: String! {
        get {
            return _providerName
        }
        set {
            _providerName = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would avoid doing that because you don't know how the superclass implements the property. It might be computed from some other place, in which case, you have just broken the superclass. This is not a criticism of your answer, which is correct in the context, but a criticism of what the question is trying to do.

Comment: @JeremyP I agree, but in this case there was no choice, the official sample code also implements the sub class like this so I also checked the code in the framework and it was ok. I hope there will a fix if the swift version of the framework comes out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in your code

```
private(set) var _providerName: String!
```

The above line will just apply private for set and would be internal for set, which in turn will give you readonly behaviour.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Just tried with _providerName but it creates a different variable. Doesn't compile with providerName either: "Overriding var must be as accessible as the declaration it overrides"